# In Spring Mvc What would be it..?

Tags: rest, api, spring-mvc

If i did This in Spring MVC

```
@Controller
public class Employee{

  @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
  public String create(){
    return "hello"
  }

}
```

Is it a Restful Web service Or simply a web service or API..???

Assuming here "hello" is a view in jsp..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `@Controller` you're building a MVC application. If you want to create REST API you need to use `@RestController` and not returning a HTML page but JSON or XML content.

Jackson embedded in Spring framework will serialize content for you. Just return your Object or Array and by default it will converted to json

Comment: Thanks Martin
I Got it RestController Will enable ResponseBody and "hello" will be no more further treated as a page 
Am i Right?

Comment: With `@Controller` spring will try to process `hello` html page but with `@RestController` it will return content "hello"

Comment: Ok.
Got it,Thanks Brother

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. I am getting this messsage lol.